# Debugging Ionic 2 app with google maps

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, ionic2, cordova-plugins

This questions relates to an Angular2 / Typescript / Ionic 2 application.
I understand that when you install the google maps plugin (cordova-plugin-googlemaps) your map will only be visible if you actually deploy and run your code on a device or an emulator. However, for development purposes it is a lot faster though to just debug in a browser.(eg use *ionic serve*)

**Question:** Can you develop something with the *cordova-plugin-googlemaps* AND debug this application in a browser? Is there maybe a better approach.

Please note that I reasonably new to Ionic & Cordova.

Comment: This is an alternative which uses Google Maps API: https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/

Comment: I have tried this and it can run on browser. But if you need to get information like geolocation etc, you will need to use a plugin

Comment: Thanks Huiting. I was aware of that approach. However, one of the reasons you would use the cordova-plugin is that this uses the Goggle Maps Android API, because there is no access quotas. My understanding is that the Javascript API has quotas that cannot be exceeded (unless you pay!). Apart from that there are other limitations, like the ones you pointed out.

Comment: I see. Didn't know the quota was different for Google Maps Android and Javscript API. Thanks for sharing! The quota for Javascript API is free up to 25,000 map loads per day so unless it is for a huge project, quite hard to reach